# How to enter static canvas layout in Reportlab Frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, pdf-generation, reportlab

I am trying to create a document that has Frames that can be given a defined layout from Canvas and then use that same format for multiple frames.

So ideally this frame would be able to grow depending on a Flowable paragraph size inside of the frame. So there would be a header of sorts in each frame followed by a paragraph of varying size. I have been beating my head against the docs trying to figure this out. My frames should also stack one on top of the other. So depending on the size, if there is one Frame on a page with a lot of text in the Paragraph, probably only one Frame will fit on the page. But if there was two Frames that had small enough Paragraphs, those two Frames would fit on one page.

For what it is worth, here is some code I started:

```
from reportlab.platypus import BaseDocTemplate, Frame, Paragraph, NextPageTemplate, PageBreak, \
    PageTemplate, NextFrameFlowable
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import landscape, letter
from reportlab.rl_config import defaultPageSize
from reportlab.lib.units import mm, inch
from reportlab.lib.colors import *
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, Frame, Spacer, SimpleDocTemplate

styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
logo_image = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\FlaskReportApp\application\static\images\logo.JPG'


doc = BaseDocTemplate('basedoc.pdf', defaultPageSize=letter, showBoundary=1)


def foot1(canvas, doc):
    canvas.saveState()
    canvas.setFont('Times-Roman', 14)
    canvas.drawString(inch, 0.75 * inch, "Page %d" % doc.page)
    canvas.drawImage(logo_image, 45, 685, width=150, preserveAspectRatio=True)
    canvas.restoreState()


# Two Columns
frame1 = Frame(doc.leftMargin, inch*8, doc.width, inch*2, id='col1', showBoundary=1)

frame2 = Frame(doc.leftMargin, inch*5.5, doc.width, inch*2, id='col2', showBoundary=1)

template = PageTemplate(id='TwoBoxKeystroke', frames=[frame1, frame2], onPage=foot1)

doc.addPageTemplates([template])

story = []
story.append(Paragraph("Frame one box,  " * 20, styles['Normal']))
story.append(Paragraph("Frame two box,  " * 20, styles['Normal']))

doc.build(story)
```

How do you exactly cause a frame to by dynamic in size depending on something like a varying Paragraph size inside a frame?

Answer (score 1):

Frames are typically at fixed positions within a given type of page layout, and the page layout in use is switched for even/odd/first/last/chapter pages. This mechanism is operated by the DocTemplate largely without knowledge of the flowables themselves.

The one time I've altered this was by inserting a `platypus.NextPageTemplate('chapter-{}'.format(chapter))` flowable, usually immediately followed by a `platypus.PageBreak()` which lets you switch the `PageTemplate` to use on the next page.

In my case the `NextPageTemplate` had some canvas-level drawing (outside of flowables) to produce a coloured marker down the outer page leaf highlighting the current chapter. It worked as follows:

- Use the `doc = platypus.BaseDocTemplate()` document template.
- create a `platypus.PageTemplate(frames=..., id=..., onPage=..)` for each chapter in a list, where
- `onPage` was a callable that renders the appropriate marker active on the canvas, partially-applied with the same id.
- add all the PageTemplates to a list and register it with `doc.addPageTemplates(templates)`
- The id of the `PageTemplate` to use for all subsequent pages is the argument to  `platypus.NextPageTemplate(id)`

Perhaps you can create the Layouts you need by measuring the text and setup the templates in advance. Otherwise you might want to keep the Frames fixed (full-page), and experiment with padding/margin around your Paragraph flowables to achieve the look you want.

Alternatively it might be so specialist that you throw new pages yourself onto the canvas and do the layout of frames by hand and append one paragraph at a time to a new Frame and draw it on the canvas.